# MaxAutoWidth in WPF

Tags: wpf, layout

Is there a good way to limit the Auto Width of an element or Grid Column?
I want to limit the Auto Width only, but allow any user changes.

For example, I want to allow GridSplitter to arbitrarily resize the column, but the initial (Auto) Width should not exceed a specific value. Same for the elements -- I want to allow resizing, but limit the Width they have if never resized.

MaxWidth works exactly as opposite -- it does not affect Auto Width of Grid Columns (it might be a bug), but limits the resized width.

Is there any good solution that works for (almost) any element or Grid part?

Answer (score 1):

Try binding the `MaxWidth` to the `Width` and use a `IValueConverter` to react to changes from `Auto` to specific values.

Comment: So basically use the MaxWidth, but remove it as soon as the Width stops being Auto? Very good idea -- thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, this causes a problem -- user can not resize the element unless he already has resized the element.

Comment: Since this is a one-time thing, you could also try to react on the GridSplitter.Click and unset MaxWidth at the moment the users starts the drag.

Answer (score 0):

In the grid column set the width you want the column to start at. Any changes to the column width made by the user using the grid splitter will overwrite the width you start with.